# Can I nest a if() within filter() dplyr?

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

Is it possible to nest `if()` statements inside of dplyr `filter()`

Is this valid (doesn't look like it)

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
```

// doesn't work

```
 sample_data %>%
      filter(if(input$device != "All") {Device == input$device},
             if(input$channel != "All") {Channel == input$channel},
             if(input$landing != "All") {Landing == input$landing}
        )
```

As opposed to:

```
// works
sample_data %>%
  filter(Device == input$device,
         Channel == input$channel,
         Landing == input$landing
    )
```

What's the prescribed way of doing this? I would like to make my filters conditional

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  From the syntax you showed, it may not work

Comment: @akrun I will except this is part of a shiny app and making a reproducible example I figured would add a lot of code blocks. I was hoping my question might be common enough or recognizable enough in it's current format. Given this is within Shiny context should I still add more code (ui.R, server.R, build sample data frame etc?)

Comment: okay, regarding working with shiny, you have to mention it in the post

Comment: `filter(Device == ifelse(input$device != "All", input$device, Device))`, maybe, or use `filter_` if you're feeling ambitious

Comment: @alistaire thanks. So each dimension (Device, Channel, Landing) will need it's own filter() function?

Comment: I would suggest not to nest `if` and `filter`. `if ` responsible for dealing with user interface and , `filter` to subset the data.

Comment: Nope. If that works (which I'm 100% on without testing), you could put all three similar conditions within one `filter` call, which effectively just joins them with `&`, which is fine.

Comment: Hi @alistaire I tried with ifelse() but failed

Comment: @ImranAli thanks for the feedback. What would be a appropriate approach to this?

Comment: @ImranAli User interface? `if` is part of basic control flow.

Comment: @alistaire, in this specific scenario  `if` is testing one of the UI elements. "less is more" isn't always the right approach, separating the code would make it much more readable. consider reading your own code after six months or a year.

Comment: @ImranAli I agree readability is a noble goal, but in this case `input$device` (etc.) is the name of a variable. If you can't do anything on the server side with user-determined variables, there's not much point for Shiny. You may have a valid larger point, though: it's possible to rearrange the UI to avoid the issue altogether.

Comment: I expanded out my code block per the advise on this comment thread. This does appear to be working but would have been neater to nest if() within filter(). I wonder if there's a more efficient way than what I've done:filtered <- reactive({
    if(input$device != "All") {
        sample_data <- filter(sample_data, Device == input$device)}
    if(input$channel != "All") {
      sample_data <- filter(sample_data, Channel == input$channel)}
    if(input$landing != "All") {
      sample_data <- filter(sample_data, Landing == input$landing)}
    sample_data})

Comment: I think [Basic DataTable](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html) example on the shiny rstudio gallery is ideal. Assign `data` variable to the entire dataset, three simple if to check for `All` conidition, subset and reassign `data` variable.

Comment: You could try `filter(input$device == "All" | Device == input$device,
             input$channel == "All" | Channel == input$channel,
             input$landing == "All" | Landing == input$landing
             )`

Comment: @GregoryDemin this works and looks much nicer, thanks!